# File revtex4-1.cls is missing... overwritten by 4-2 after update?

Tags: revtex, updating

I updated my TeXLive and lost the `revtex4-1.cls` class. The package *revtex* contains now `revtex4-2.cls`. Old version 4.0 is accessible by installing *revtex4* package. There is a new package *revtex4-1* which should restore the dependencies, and should contain `revtex4-1.cls`, but after installing it, the problem remains. The package *revtex4-1* installs only docs, not `revtex4-1.cls`. Is it a bug, and is going to be fixed, or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Well the new package revtex4-1 does install revtex4-1.cls  -- but in the wrong place (in the doc folder). That's an installation error, I will report it on the texlive list. It should be correct tomorrow or the day after.

Comment: In the meanwhile, if you're running TeX from the terminal with bash, `TEXINPUTS=$(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFMAIN)/doc/latex/revtex4-1//: pdflatex filename` will do. You should be using `revtex4-2` anyhow.

Comment: @Ulrike, yes, you're right, thanks. Indeed the `revtex4-1.cls` lands in docs. I'll just wait a bit with the update. @egreg, sure, there is a number ways to make it run, but a lot of my coworkers who I write papers with opened terminal 2-3 times in a life. So I was looking for the solution for the latex paper that compiles on both updated and not updated systems.